# Origins of "Mark" as "symbol"

Tags: etymology

friends! How is it going? : )

I've been conducting a heavy research on the word "mark" for the past month, but unfortunately I'm far from being a linguist, so I lack decent resources... hahaha

I know when and where the word "mark" started and the names it took throught the centuries (I have already checked the first 10-15 Google Pages), but there's one thing that I still can't fully grasp (and that's what I need the most): when, AND HOW, exactly the word changed from "boundary" to "sign" and "symbol".

For instance: some say that by the 13th century it changed from "boundary" to "sign of a boundary"... How do they know that? Any proofs?

It is also related to "marksman" (apparently because they marked the places they would shoot at), but then again, no explanatory texts on that.

Simply put: I know the whole word tree, but I lack a few referenced explanations like every decent thesis' need.

Main reference: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mark

**Thank you all!**

Comment: "Mark" doesn't mean "symbol", to my knowledge, but "sign, signifier, indicator" are all good, and may proceed from the nature of a boundary: being a legal fiction of sorts, this invisible thing is usually *indicated* by something else. Also, I wonder if the idea of ownership/propriety in a boundary is the one that influenced French *marque*, on the other hand.

Comment: You are right, @LukeSawczak, it's not "symbol" at first, but the meaning "sign" is applied in many contexts that it could be interpreted in such way.

For instance: brand mark, which is the symbol of a brand. (Like Apple's logo.)

Also, according to Oxford: _"A line, figure, or symbol made as an indication or record of something."_

Comment: Look here at Grimm's *Deutsches Wörterbuch* http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GM01411#XGM01411

Comment: AMAZING TIP, @jknappen
That's exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

> How do they know that? Any proofs?

You can’t prove a negative, so there’s no way to prove that a word *didn’t* have such-and-such meaning before a certain date.  What we do is, we look at the earliest mention of a word where it clearly seems to mean X.  Then we known that meaning X dates *at least* as early as the date of that document.  In fact it had that meaning earlier (or the writer wouldn’t have used it!), but there’s no way to know how much earlier.  All we can say is that *by* that date it already had the meaning (the technical term is [*terminus ante quem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminus_post_quem)).

Of course, dating *all* earliest mentions of *all* meanings of *all* words is quite a monumental task! You English speakers are actually spoiled for choice: the Oxford English Dictionary—the [big, multi-volume one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary)—is probably one of the best such compendiums in all languages, if not the best;  it’s been 160+ years in the making and by now it has accumulated a lot of data.

Whenever you are interested in a particular word, I heartily recommend you head to the nearest public library and consult the OED.  The entry for "mark" lists **42** meanings (not counting idioms), all of them with copious attestations of ancient use, and with most of them  grouped into two main branches:

- I. a boundary, a border between lands. Earliest English attestation is in [the Metres of Boethius](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/114169?rskey=NChHNy&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) (880–950) xi.65: *Hæfð se ilca god eorðan and wætere mearce gesette* (“having set the border for the same good earth and water”, if I’m not mistaken—someone who actually knows OE please correct this).
- II. an object marking a boundary; a sign. First attestation in this family is the Old English Hexateuch (traditionally said to date around the 950s): xxiv.4. *Moyses..getimbrode an weofod æt þam munte nyðeweardon & twelf mearca on twelf Israhela mægðum.* (something about Moses building up the mound an altar and twelve 'marks' of the twelve Israeli tribes).  It also pops up in Ælfric’s *Grammar* (late 10th century), denoting ‘a banner, a standard’: *‘Victricia tollite signa‘, nymað þa sigefæstan mearca* (=victorious banner).

Modern ‘mark’ has has a quite complicated etymology, too, merging together at least three different cognates: Old English *mearc* (strong feminine declension) = boundary, borderland, present with this meaning in several Germanic languages; *mearc* (strong neuter declension), more related to the meaning of ‘sign’ (these may give different reflexes in other languages, e.g. Middle Dutch *marke* vs. *marc/merc*, or Old Icelandic *mǫrk* vs. *mark*); and, thirdly, as a Scandinavian loan.

This is all scratching the surface.  By a rough count, the OED entry for ‘mark’ **alone** has some 17 *thousand* words (an entire novella about *one* word).  So if you’re interested in historical details about a word, go check the OED.

Comment: How did you conclude that OP is an English speaker?

Comment: Dear @boiko, I'm always reading about searching the OED, but I never find those references like you mentioned.

Could you give me a weblink to where you found it?

Comment: By the way, you can't even imagine how valuable that description of "banner" is important to me. It almost solves my whole research! Could I have your name to mention you formally???

Edit: Acabei de reparar que você é brasileiro, @boiko Você pode resolver esse meu problema milenar com pouquíssimo esforço; me contate diretamente se puder, por favor!

Comment: Opa @Rich, você precisa de uma edição impressa do OED, ou uma assinatura online (paga). Ambas são provavelmente caras demais pra você bancar do próprio bolso. Você precisa achar uma biblioteca que ofereça; a maioria das bibliotecas grandes deve ter. No caso eu usei a da minha faculdade (na Alemanha).

Comment: Btw meu nome inteiro é Leonardo Ferreira da Silva Boiko mas eu não acho que esta resposta mereça uma citação. Cite o OED :)

Comment: Consegui acesso ao OED! :D Muito obrigado por essa iluminação, @boiko , você não faz ideia do quanto você clareou as minhas ideias com aquelas duas quotes! 

Você poderia me dizer como você fez aquelas duas traduções? Foi conhecimento ou tool?

Comment: Você sabe me dizer uma boa fonte para etimologia, @boiko ?
Tipo: eu sei que "marksman" vem de "mark", mas não sei porquê.
Eu preciso saber porquê o "marco alemão" tem essa origem, mas não sei porquê.
(Fonte gratuita, paga... tudo é bem-vindo.)

Comment: Eu mal arranho o inglês antigo, só fui vendo palavra a palavra no Wiktionary (por isso pode ter erros).  As boas fontes que conheço o pessoal já citou—OED pro inglês, e Grimms pro alemão. (Note que o OED tem entrada para *marksman*, que além de informativa aponta pra de *markman*, que aponta pro alemão medieval *marcman*, que (modernizando a grafia pra procurar) tem um sentido que eu não esperava listado no [Grimms](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GM01492#XGM01492).

Comment: Fora isso, quando se pesquisa etimologia de línguas indo-européias em geral é útil procurar algo do proto-indo-europeu; eu não entendo muito porque minha área é o japonês, mas tem vários recursos online como [este](https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/lex/master/1302).  O Grimms menciona várias línguas germânicas com um sentido de "moeda" pro étimo (frísio, nórdico), então talvez valha a pena correr atrás de um dicionário de proto-germânico também, ver se acrescentam algo.

Comment: Putz, só agora que fui notar essas origens de "marksmann"... então é puramente ligada a "march" (fronteira).

Enfim, consegui achar TODAS as respostas que eu tava procurando há eras com as tuas dicas (e inclusive me lembrar dessa dúvida desgraçada); te sou eternamente grato, @boiko ; muito obrigado mesmo! Take care.